# Permutation of 4-digit numbers

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> How many even integers between 1000 and 9999 (both inclusive) have distinct digits?

I filled the last digit with 5 number the second last with 9 and like that 1st and second digit with with 8 and 7 possibilities but the answer won't come, please point out the flaw and the correct process. Any help will be useful, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We make two cases:

- If the last digit is zero, we have free rein over choosing the other digits. Thus there are $9×8×7=504$ admissible numbers in this case.
- Otherwise, the last digit is one of `2468` and there are only eight choices for the first digit (zero being excluded from that position). After that, eight choices remain for the second digit and seven are available for the third. There are $4×8×8×7=1792$ admissible numbers in this case.

Summing up, there are 2296 admissible numbers in all.

Answer (score 4):

Hint : 
You counted those cases too, when the first digit was $0$.Therefore you'll have to take different cases when the last digit (I.e. unit digit) is equal to $0$, and another when it isn't.

Comment: I was going to edit and add a detailed solution, but @ParclyTaxel has already added one.Therefore now I'm not adding, you can refer complete solution there.